# Is it possible to lineplot more than 6 columns with seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.6, seaborn, line-plot

Is it possible to plot more than 6 columns using seaborn.lineplot?

When I try to plot it I receive following error message:

```
These `style` levels are missing dashes: {'LOGAN', 'HB20S', 'GOL'}
```

It works if I index the dataframe for 6 columns.

Here's the code that works:

```
sns.lineplot(data=movida_2.iloc[:,:6])
```

Comment: It's quite unlikely that seaborn would restrict plotting to 6 columns. But feel free to provide a [mcve] of the issue such that one can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 38):

The problem is that lineplot uses dashed lines for the second and any further column but the standard style only supports dashes for the first 6 colors.

This should work for you:

```
sns.lineplot(data=movida_2, dashes=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sns.lineplot(data=movida_2, marker = "0", dashes=False)
```

You can change the marker type as well.